# Why my browser shows blank page when I run react?

Tags: html, reactjs, sass

I have a bunch of html code and I am breaking them to react component. I am new to react.js. I made few changes in footer section, but when i run localhost in browser, it displays nothing. can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

```
class Footer extends Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="footer">
         <div className="container">
           <div className="col-md-5 f-first-part">
             <div className="row">
               <div className="col-sm-5 f-add-part">

                 <div className="contact-info">
                                <p className="address">123</p>
                                <p className="email"><a href=""></a></p>
                                <p className="tele"><a href=""> 03580368</a></p>
                 </div>

                  <div className="large-3 large-offset-2 columns">
                    <ul className="menu vertical">
                      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                  <div className="large-3 columns">
                    <ul className="menu vertical">
                      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                 </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

export default Footer;
```

Comment: what does your setup look like? can you show some code please?

Comment: I have added my footer

Comment: The component won't show until you render it 
Have you added 
ReactDOM.render(<Footer/>, document.getElementById('main-page')) ?

Also make sure you indent the code properly, your class footer is outside the code

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read from your question,
**this is your code**

**Footer.js**

```
import Footer from '/your-path-to-/footer.js'
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Footer extends Component {
 render () {
  return (
  <div>
    <div className="footer">
     <div className="container">
       <div className="col-md-5 f-first-part">
         <div className="row">
           <div className="col-sm-5 f-add-part">

             <div className="contact-info">
                            <p className="address">123</p>
                            <p className="email"><a href=""></a></p>
                            <p className="tele"><a href=""> 03580368</a></p>
             </div>

              <div className="large-3 large-offset-2 columns">
                <ul className="menu vertical">
                  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <div className="large-3 columns">
                <ul className="menu vertical">
                  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Footer/>, document.getElementById('main'));
```

You need to define a container for the component in order to render it,
in this case I've created a index.html file with a div element whose id is main,

**your index.html**

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

this will load the component there, I don't know if this is what you need, you'll need to provide more details.

**Also check your console, important information is displayed there**

Regards